# Customize function in R using using data.table to group by doesn't recognize group argument

Tags: r, function, data.table, group

I'm simply trying to create a function to sum by group. But, it seems the function never finds  'my_group' argument. The solution needs to be inside a function. 'data.table' and 'tidyverse' options do work outside the function.

What am I missing here?

```
data=data.table(
group= c('a','b','b','c','c','c'),
value=1:6
)

sum_value_by_group<-function(dt, val, my_group) {
  dt[,group_value:= sum(val), by = my_group]
  return(dt)
}

sum_value_by_group(data, value, group)
```

Getting this error:
Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object 'group' not found

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `get` and pass the column names as strings.

```
library(data.table)

sum_value_by_group<-function(dt, val, my_group) {
  dt[, .(group_value = sum(get(val))), by = list(group = get(my_group))]
}
sum_value_by_group(data, 'value', 'group')

#   group group_value
#1:     a           1
#2:     b           5
#3:     c          15
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak Shah.  It does work but I don't understand why do we need to do this? Can you provide any insights?

Comment: the `by` clause can be a string and the selected column can be provided as a (vector)string as well using `.SDcols`, so one could use `dt[, .(group_value = sum(.SD)), by = my_group, .SDcols = val]`